# Flutter - Showing dialog behind existing dialog

Tags: flutter

I have a dialog on screen (first pic), and then an action causes another dialog to appear via showDialog. The second dialog appears on top of the first one and obscures it of course (second pic), but I want to make it so that it appears below the first one instead (third pic). Dismissing the first dialog in this case should show the second dialog that's just below it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
onPressed: () => showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) => Dialog(
    backgroundColor: Colors.red.shade200,
    child: TextButton(
        onPressed: () => showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) => Dialog(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.green.shade200,
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 100,
                    child: TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: const Text("Second"),
                    ),
                  ),
                )),
        child: const Text("First")),
  ),
)
```

I feel like I would want to somehow insert the second dialog route before the first dialog route, instead of pushing it to the front of the navigator (which showDialog does), although I don't know how this would work. I tried playing around with it and I could only manage a very hacky half-solution involving pushing an empty dummy dialog route right before the first showDialog, and then using Navigator.replace to replace the dummy route with a DialogRoute representing the second dialog. This works surprisingly well, but not well enough, and anyway it's complicated and not very usable. If only NavigatorState exposed an insert method I think this could be more easily doable. There has to be a way to make this work right?

Comment: You can pop the first dialogue and then show the second one. if that flow works for you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use pushReplacement() or popAndPushNamed() as per Your requirement for routing  instead of push() or pop()